# How to get ipv4 addresses of all computers on a network in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, network-programming

I have a Windows Forms app in Visual basic that is currently sending messages back and forth between two computers. Currently, the user has to manually enter the ipv4 address of the receiver of the message. what I would like to do is put the ipv4 addresses of all the computers on the network into a combo box so the user has a list to pick from.

I have searched a whole bunch of different forums and am unable to find a working solution.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim strHostName As String
    Dim strIPAddress As String
    Dim running As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
        strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
        Me.Text = strIPAddress
        txtIP.Text = strIPAddress
        running = True

        'run listener on separate thread
        Dim listenTrd As Thread
        listenTrd = New Thread(AddressOf StartServer)
        listenTrd.IsBackground = True
        listenTrd.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        running = False
    End Sub

    Sub StartServer()
        Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(CInt(txtPort.Text))
        Dim requestCount As Integer
        Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
        Dim messageReceived As Boolean = False
        While running
            messageReceived = False
            serverSocket.Start()
            msg("Server Started")
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()
            msg("Accept connection from client")
            requestCount = 0

            While (Not (messageReceived))
                Try
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1
                    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
                    Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length)
                    Dim dataFromClient As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
                    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.Length)
                    'invoke into other thread
                    txtOut.Invoke(Sub()
                                      txtOut.Text += dataFromClient
                                      txtOut.Text += vbNewLine
                                  End Sub)

                    messageReceived = True
                    Dim serverResponse As String = "Server response " + Convert.ToString(requestCount)
                    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                    networkStream.Flush()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    End
                End Try
            End While
            clientSocket.Close()
            serverSocket.Stop()
            msg("exit")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Sub

    Sub msg(ByVal mesg As String)
        mesg.Trim()
        Console.WriteLine(" >> " + mesg)
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteData(ByVal data As String, ByRef IP As String)
        Try
            txtOut.Text += data.PadRight(1)
            txtOut.Text += vbNewLine
            txtMsg.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine("Sending message """ & data & """ to " & IP)
            Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient()
            client.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), CInt(txtPort.Text)))
            Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
            Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
            stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
        Catch ex As Exception
            msg(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        If Not (txtMsg.Text = vbNullString) AndAlso Not (txtIP.Text = vbNullString) Then
            WriteData(txtMsg.Text, txtIP.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtMsg_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtMsg.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If Not (txtMsg.Text = vbNullString) AndAlso Not (txtIP.Text = vbNullString) Then
                WriteData(txtMsg.Text, txtIP.Text)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
        'find all local addresses and put in combobox (button will be removed later)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have tried here? What is your expected result, and what is the actual result? Do you have any error messages or unexpected output? I assume that you have taken the [tour], checked [ask] and confirmed that the code you have supplied is a [mcve]?

Comment: The code I have tried has given no errors and just has no output. My expected output would be a list of ipv4 addresses (all the computers on the network)

Comment: domain or workgroup?

Comment: What are the values when debugging and stepping for example `strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` and `strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()`

Comment: @Devcon I would like to get all computers on the domain.

Comment: @RandomCoder Those two lines just return my IP address(strHostName = LiamsLaptop[the name of my laptop] and strIPAddress = 172.23.33.163[the IP address of my laptop), what I am looking to get is all the pcs on my domain. If it is easier I can probably make do with all the pc names instead of the IPs.

Answer (score 0):

For PC names "as you suggested in your comments", I used this at work to get pc names i was on domain, try it:
AFAIK it works on domains...
Make sure you have a listbox on your form, or change listbox and populate in your combobox directly, play with that as you like :)

```
Private Delegate Sub UpdateDelegate(ByVal s As String)
Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetNetworkComputers)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    t.IsBackground = True
    t.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub AddListBoxItem(ByVal s As String)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(s)
End Sub

Private Sub GetNetworkComputers()

    Try

        Dim alWorkGroups As New ArrayList
        Dim de As New DirectoryEntry
        de.Path = "WinNT:"
        For Each d As DirectoryEntry In de.Children
            If d.SchemaClassName = "Domain" Then alWorkGroups.Add(d.Name)
            d.Dispose()
        Next
        For Each workgroup As String In alWorkGroups
            de.Path = "WinNT://" & workgroup
            For Each d As DirectoryEntry In de.Children
                If d.SchemaClassName = "Computer" Then
                    Dim del As UpdateDelegate = AddressOf AddListBoxItem
                    Me.Invoke(del, d.Name)
                End If
                d.Dispose()
            Next
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(Ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

POC:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this code, however, I have decided to take a different approach and have a button that will find computers with the app open. I have a plan on how I am going to do that. (this way I don't just have a bunch of IPs of computers that I won't even be able to send a message to)

Comment: I can help you with that too if you ask in another thread, but for this thread tick my answer